# Pundit : Custom redirection within one user action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, pundit

I'm trying to centralize authentification in pundit policies instead of having it in my controllers. It works well but I lost some flexibility in customizing redirection and flash message.

How could I transfer the information about which authentification didn't pass to the Pundit::NotAuthorizedError rescuing function ? One action can have 2 steps of authentification: 1. user.paid? 2. user.is_allowed_to_update? and I want custom message and redirection for each case.

The `exception.query` solution is not working cause it only allow to customize flash and redirection for each action and not within one action.

Below is a more detailed explanation of the situation

```
WITHOUT PUNDIT
Comment_Controller
def update
    if user.didnt_pay?
        flash[:message] = nice_message
        redirect_to payment_page_path
    elsif user.is_not_allowed_to_perform_action
        flash[:message] = less_nice_message
        redirect_to dashboard_path
    end
end
```

And now

```
WITH PUNDIT
Comment_Controller
def update
    authorize @comment
end

Comment_policy
def update?
    user.paid? && user_is_allowed_to_perform_action
end

ApplicationController
rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized
def user_not_authorized
    flash[:message] = one_message_for_all_error # THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO CUSTOMIZE
    redirect_to one_path_for_all_error # THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO CUSTOMIZE
end
```

Answer (score 3):

A possibility for customizing this error messages it to set the expected message in the `Policy` and later getting it from the controller. How to do so?

The `exception` object you get as an argument in the controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def user_not_authorized(exception)
  end
end
```

comes with a `policy` attribute which links you to the offending policy. So, lets say that in your policy you want to set a particular message when some clause is not fulfilled:

```
class AnimalPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  attr_accessor :error_message

  def new?
    if !authorization_clause
      @error_message = "Something terrible happened"
      false
    else
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Hence, in your controller, you would have to set this `error_message` into your `flash` or wherever you want it to be:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def user_not_authorized(exception)
    flash[:error] = exception.policy.try(:error_message) || "Default error message"

    redirect_to root_path 
  end
end
```

It's a bit clumsy solution, but it worked for me

Comment: I just mentioned the case of a customized comment; the case of adding a custom `redirect` path follows mutatis mutandis.

Answer (score 0):

In my solution I propose two methods, one when the user has a good answer the other when the answer is not favorable ... pundit has a method (user_not_authorized) which allows to manage that one could duplicate and Adapt to your suggestions

```
 def update

    if user.didnt_pay?

       authorize @comment
       user_congratulation

    elsif user.is_not_allowed_to_perform_action

        user_not_authorized 

     end

end
```

in **ApplicationController**

past this **rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized**

and after You'll create two private methods in your controller called

user_not_authorized and user_congratulation

```
   private

     def user_not_authorized
        flash[:alert] = "less_nice_message"
        redirect_to dashboard_path
     end


     def user_congratulation
         flash[:alert] = "nice_message"
         redirect_to payment_page_path
     end

   end
```

for more information visit this link https://github.com/elabs/pundit#rescuing-a-denied-authorization-in-rails

Although this post is old, I thought fit to answer because I was also in need of a good answer, which was not the case! I hope to have helped

Comment: Please take some time to format your code correctly.